# How to pass outerTheme to makeStyles()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a theme defined in `outerTheme.js`:

```
import { createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const outerTheme = createTheme({

  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#0D4E7C",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#EC9A1F",
    },

  },
});

export default outerTheme;
```

And then in my main:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import outerTheme from "outerTheme";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  staticGrid: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
}));

function App() {

  const classes = useStyles(outerTheme);

  return (
    <Container fixed>
      <Grid container className={classes.staticGrid}>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
export default MyAccount;
```

In the code above it looks like `theme.palette.secondary.main` doesn't really have the value from `outerTheme`. I suppose I made some mistake with importing the `outerTheme`. What is wrong with it?